# Instructing a batch file to do something depending on output

Tags: batch-file, wget

I have a situation where I would like the a batch file to do one of two different actions.

E.g. I am using WGET to download a file:

Situation 1: WGET outputs "404 Not Found" - start batch1.bat

or

Situation 2: WGET outputs "Download successful" - start batch2.bat

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does WGET raise an error (as detected by ERRORLEVEL) when it hits a 404 Not Found? If so, include somethihg like

```
IF errorlevel == 1 GOTO :WGET_Error
```

immediately after the call. If not, you might have to redirect the output to a file, read and parse the file (perhaps using the FOR command) to see if the first line is "404 Not Found", and go from there.

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily have to output it to a file for a for command.  For commands can run on the output of a command, but most likely have to use delimiters.